# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\pyrll\emlhome.php on line 15

Tags: mysql

I've tried other answers similar to mine but in vain.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=isset($_POST['con']);
include("header.php");
include("dbconnection.php");
$logindt = date("Y-m-d");
$qresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE logintime >  '$logindt 00:00:00' AND logintime <  '$logindt 23:59:59' AND empid ='$_SESSION[emid]'");
$counts = mysql_num_rows($qresult);
$attid = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
    $insdb ="INSERT INTO attendance(empid,logintime) VALUES ('$_SESSION[emid]','$attid')";
    mysql_query($insdb,$con);//line 15
```

Comment: check for isset($_SESSION[emid])  isset($attid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says.

Line 15 is:

```
mysql_query($insdb,$con);//line 15
```

`$con` is defined on line 3.

```
$con=isset($_POST['con']);
```

This is indeed a boolean indicating if `$_POST['con']` exists. `mysql_query` expects a 2nd parameter that indentifies the connection (whatever `mysql_connect` returns) -if- you define it. I don't think that is needed here, so simply remove the second parameter and I think it should work.

Comment: thanks so mush I removed the con and it worked. so the dbconnection does it all

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error()

> Returns the text of the error message from previous MySQL operation

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php